# $(document).ready(function () Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="deleteAdress('@_address.AddressID','@Model.CustomerID','@ViewData["appid"]','@ViewData["_retVal"]')">Delete</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var customerID = $("#hidcustomerid").val();
    if (customerID != "0") {
       function deleteAdress(adressId, customerId, appid, retVal) {
            window.location.href = '/Customer/DeleteAdress/?adressId=' + adressId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&appid=" + appid + "&retVal=" + retVal;
       }
   }
});
```

If I use `deleteAdress` function **outside** of `$(document).ready()` the function **works**.

If I use `deleteAdress` **inside** of `$(document).ready()` the function displays an error when clicking the button.

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteAdress is not defined

Remaining HTML:

```
<table>
    @foreach (ObjectModelLibrary.Address _address in Model.Addresses.List)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deleteAdress('@_address.AddressID','@Model.CustomerID','@ViewData["appid"]','@ViewData["_retVal"]')"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Delete</button>
            </th>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

How can I use `deleteAdress` function inside of `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: You are declaring a locally scoped function inside function. Move it outside all functions.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie JavaScript only has function scope, so the function will be hoisted to the `$(document).ready` callback function's scope, not kept within the `if` block. You probably know this, but it's not entirely clear in your comment and may confuse OP.

Comment: @ajp15243: I should have realised someone would take me literally (rather than stating where the function was declared) :) Corrected.

Comment: @soner: Um... Nobody here is "hacking your system."

Comment: use @DerVampyr's answer.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, avoid using *attribute-based* event handlers (like `onclick`) and register them the jQuery way. This keeps the code and registration together and avoids this sort of problem. Use `data-` attributes to supply the IDs etc. (basically ignore almost every answer you will get) :)

Comment: I also added an Ajax call example, so you do not need to leave the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned initially in comment, your function is not global, so cannot be seen by an `onclick` handler.

Secondly, having an `if` around a function has no effect (http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gdptaxvv/) as the function is *hoisted* to the top within its parent scope so it always exists. You could use an alternate method of declaring the function to avoid that, but I do not recommend it e.g. `var deleteAddress = function(){}`, but the scope still blocks an `onclick` handler from seeing it.

As a general guideline, don't use *attribute-based* handlers with jQuery (e.g. `onclick=""`). It separates the handler from the event registration and does not support multiple handlers.

1. Add a new class to identify your delete button(s). e.g `class="deleteAddress"` in the example below.
2. Inject any key values into the items as `data-` attributes and handle the event the jQuery way. This also means your conditional check will work as you intended:

**e.g. HTML with data- attributes:**

```
<table>
@foreach (ObjectModelLibrary.Address _address in Model.Addresses.List) 
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            <button class="deleteAddress btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" data-addressId="@_address.AddressID" data-customerId="@Model.CustomerID" data-appId="@(ViewData["appid"])" data-retVal="@(ViewData["_retVal"])">Delete</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**Note:** *I added some `()` wrappers on the two attributes I felt might confuse Razor, but probably not needed unless it gives an error.*

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var customerID = $("#hidcustomerid").val();
    if (customerID != "0") {
        $('.deleteAddress').click(function(){
              // Get key values from data- attributes "of the clicked button"
              var addressId = $(this).data("addressId"); 
              var customerId = $(this).data("customerId"); 
              var appid = $(this).data("appId"); 
              var retVal = $(this).data("retVal"); 
              window.location.href = '/Customer/DeleteAddress/?addressId=' + addressId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&appid=" + appid + "&retVal=" + retVal;
        });
    }
});
```

The above example assumes that the buttons are one per row, so that the attributes will relate to the deletion of that row.

**Side notes:**

I would strongly suggest using Ajax for the delete and not setting the window location. You can then delete the row interactively, *without a page refresh*.

**e.g. Ajax version:**

```
$(function () {
    var customerID = $("#hidcustomerid").val();
    if (customerID != "0") {
        $('.deleteAddress').click(function(){
              // Get displayed row to delete
              var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
              // Get key values from data- attributes "of the clicked button"
              var addressId = $(this).data("addressId"); 
              var customerId = $(this).data("customerId"); 
              var appid = $(this).data("appId"); 
              var retVal = $(this).data("retVal"); 
              $.get('/Customer/DeleteAdress/?addressId=' + addressId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&appid=" + appid + "&retVal=" + retVal).done(function(){
                   // Delete succeeded, delete the screen row
                   $tr.remove();
              });
        });
    }
});
```

There is a shorter version of `$(document).ready(function(){});` available that you should use:

```
$(function(){
   // Your DOM ready code here.
});
```

it also support this version (with a locally scoped $ to avoid clashes):

```
jQuery(function($){
   // Your DOM ready code here using a locally scoped $
});
```

Comment: your solution looks the best as now.Only a problem.. I have list and .deleteAdress.click will work for all list how can i know which row clicked according to my required ?

Comment: You need to show the rest of your HTML. You can get it from a) the button pressed (if multiple deletes) or b) store the attributes in the row. Please provide your HTML and I will update to match :)

Comment: thanks for help and answer please check my question(edited html)

Comment: The above code uses the attributes *of the button clicked* so will work as-is. I will expand the example to use your code.

Comment: @soner: Updated to show my example in your sample code. It did not require changing as it was per-row anyway. I have tried to clarify all points in the answer. Just ask if anything is not clear :)

Comment: can i use id instead of class name ? like id="btnDeleteAdress" ?

Comment: @soner: Not if there is more than one button as IDs *must* be unique on a page (else jQuery can only see the first one). You do not need an ID at all in the case shown so far.

Comment: problem is about class name i can not change class name as "deleteAddress"

Comment: @soner: Can you explain why you have no control over the class names? What else is going on? So long as you can locate the elements without using an ID search, any selector will work that matches your buttons. e.g you could add a `data-delete` attribute and match those. I need more information to suggest a better solution.

Comment: i must use this "btn btn-sm btn-danger" as class name because designer said me that i must use this for design of button.

Comment: @soner: Adding extra classes has *no effect whatsoever* on your designer. Add as many extra classes as you like. He just wanted those to exist for his CSS to work :) I put them back in the example as I accidentally removed them before.

Comment: var adressId = $(this).attr('data-addressid');
                        var customerId = $(this).attr("data-customerid");
                        var appid = $(this).attr("data-appid");
                        var retVal = $(this).attr("data-retval");

worked thanks

Comment: @soner: `data('addressid')` is just a shortcut for `attr('data-addressid')`. Note the attributes are *case-sensitive* and I used mixed case in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function from within document.ready, but you should define it outside.

Comment: how come can you write me an example according to my question thanks

Comment: the document ready block is executed during page load. If you want access to the function AFTER page load, you should declare it outside of this block so it will be available. You can still call that function within document.ready, though.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to define `deleteAdress` outside the `$(document).ready()` function callback. It will then be globally accessible (functions are not available outside the scope in which they were defined).

The better option would be to refactor your code and to assign the event handler in jQuery rather than in an inline attribute:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="addressDelete"
  id='@Model.CustomerID' 
  data-address-id='@Model.AddressID' 
  data-appid='@ViewData["appid"]' 
  data-retval='@ViewData["_retVal"]'>
    Delete
</button>
```

Then bind the function with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addressDelete').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            adressId = $this.data('addressId'),
            customerId = this.id,
            appId = $this.data('appid'),
            retVal = $this.data('retval');

        window.location.href = '/Customer/DeleteAdress/?adressId=' + adressId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&appid=" + appid + "&retVal=" + retVal;
    }
});
```

This keeps your Javascript out of your HTML and makes your markup clearer, and may improve performance to boot.

Comment: Note: Using `customerId` as the HTML element `ID` is risky. It may be all numeric (likely, and invalid for HTML4), or simply not valid as an identifier. Better add a 4th `data-customerId` attribute (as I did). *Please note your data selectors are invalid for the data attributes specified, so you may want to correct them.*

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Even if it is HTML and even if it is technically invalid, it doesn't actually *matter*. Also, please clarify what is invalid about my `data` calls... (Or indeed correct them yourself.) Upvoted your (excellent) answer, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The `deleteAddress` function is only defined in the scope of the anonymous function passed to `document.ready`.  (In fact, it's only *conditionally* defined at that.  I'm not even really sure how that would work with function hoisting.)  In order to use it outside of that scope, it would need to be defined outside of that scope:

```
function deleteAdress(adressId, customerId, appid, retVal) {
    window.location.href = '/Customer/DeleteAdress/?adressId=' + adressId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&appid=" + appid + "&retVal=" + retVal;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should you? deleteAdress is a function. You can call it from any place if you want.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var customerID = $("#hidcustomerid").val();
   if (customerID != "0") {
       // dont know what you want to do here. (function is called at button onclick)
   }
}

function deleteAdress(adressId, customerId, appid, retVal) {
   window.location.href = '/Customer/DeleteAdress/?adressId=' + adressId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&appid=" + appid + "&retVal=" + retVal;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it runs the delete code immediately (not the intended behavior). Delete is on click of the delete button. This is exactly why I recommend using jQuery event registration and not attribute-based event handlers (the attributes are easily overlooked).

Comment: My intention was to put the function call where the function was... didnt check the circumstances of the function. Its right, that this version calls the function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use inline JS. Change:

```
<button type="button" onclick="deleteAdress.....
```

To:

```
<button type="button" class="deleteAddress">Delete</button>
```

And add the following to within DOM ready and it wont matter if the function is defined in DOM ready or outside. But again, you should not clatter the global scope:

```
$('.deleteAddress').on('click', deleteAddress);
```